# why app showing warning for Intune library while uploading app on app store?

Tags: ios, app-store, intune

While uploading app on app store from Xcode getting warning for IntuneMAMSwift.framework.
[image]

I am using Xcode 14.1 and mac os Monterey 12.6.3.
How do I resolve issue?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question is that IntuneMAMSwift framework developers would have to fix this.
There's already an issue logged on [their github page](https://github.com/msintuneappsdk/ms-intune-app-sdk-ios/issues/301).

As per the people reporting the issue, it seems that at the moment the build has been uploaded successfully with this warning.

From your side, if you really want this warning gone, one thing you could potentially do is to remove this framework, although I highly doubt that is feasible for you.
Another possibility, although I am not sure if that would work, is that you could try with an older version of the IntuneMAMSwift framework. Again, I highly doubt that is something you'd want to do.